# sqlalchemy pass value to subquery

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy, correlated-subquery

I am trying to do something like the following:

```
SELECT t1.thing1
FROM t1
WHERE 'some_string' NOT IN (
    SELECT t2.thing2
    FROM t2
    WHERE t2.field = t1.field1
)
```

specifically, I don't know how to access `t1.field1` in the subquery in sqlalchemy. Thanks!

EDIT: sorry, first time asking on SO, wasn't sure what to include. I'll add some info below (pseuodocode of table definitions).

```
table name: 
    t1
field: 
    field1 = UUID (primary key)
    thing1 = str

table name: 
    t2
fields: 
    field2 = foreign key (t1.field1)
    thing2 = str
    relation = relationship('t1')
```

So if there's a row in t1 with field1 equal to field 2 of a row in t2, AND 'some_string' is not in the thing2 field of t2, return the thing1 field of t1, if that makes sense.

Comment: Hey @mliuofficial, could you provide the current SQLAlchemy ORM for the tables you want to do this with?

Comment: Hello - Welcome to SO. From the first look , I wonder what is 'thing' in where filter ? do you mean t1.thing NOT IN ( . Also, please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Ferdinand55 I made some edits to my question, hopefully it is better!